# Sorting nested collections using EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, editorfor

I am using shared editor templates to render nested collections in my view with the 'EditorFor' HTML helper, similar to the following.  I'm not in love with all of these nested partial views but doing it this way names the elements appropriately so that they post back to my controller in the ViewModel without an issue.

How would I sort the order at the most resolute level of the nest?  In this case, how would I get "Budget.vbhtml" to display in Year order (descending)?

Thanks in advance!

Top-level view (Organization.vbhtml):

```
<div id="budgets">
     @Html.EditorFor(Function(org) org.OrganizationBudgets))
</div>
```

OrganizationBudget.vbhtml:

```
@ModelType CharityMVC.OrganizationBudget
@Html.EditorFor(Function(ob) ob.Budget)
```

Budget.vbhtml:

```
@ModelType CharityMVC.Budget
@Model.Year @Html.EditorFor(Function(b) b.Amount)
```

UPDATE:

It sounds like I should be doing this in my controller when I populate my Model object, but how do I sort the children or children-of-children in a linq query?  This is my current code:

```
Function Edit(ByVal id As Integer) As ActionResult
    Dim o As Organization
    Dim ovm As OrganizationViewModel

    'Load the organization from the database
    o = (From org In _db.Organizations _
        Where org.Id = id _
        Select org).FirstOrDefault()

    'Map it to the ViewModel
    ovm = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(Of Organization, OrganizationViewModel)(o)

    Return View(ovm)

End Function
```

Comment: A couple of thoughts I've had but not sure how to pursue: Use DataAnnotations to indicate sort order.  Apply the sorting in the Automapper that maps to my ViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best answer so far:

Multple LINQ queries populating the child properties like so:

```
Function Edit(ByVal id As Integer) As ActionResult
    Dim o As Organization
    Dim ovm As OrganizationViewModel

    'Load the organization from the database
    o = (From org In _db.Organizations _
        Where org.Id = id _
        Select org).FirstOrDefault()

    o.OrganizationBudgets = (From ob In _db.OrganizationBudgets _
                             Where ob.OrganizationId = o.Id _
                             Order By ob.Budget.Year Descending _
                             Select ob).ToList()


    'Map it to the ViewModel
    ovm = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(Of Organization, OrganizationViewModel)(o)

    Return View(ovm)

End Function
```